# PHP Form Processing - Joining tables using multiple user inputs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a form that takes in multiple parameters inputted by the user.  They are then used to search and retrieve a record. The query needs to join multiple tables, but because the parameter values come from the user, my code is currently creating multiple records with a cross product, i.e. same individual with multiple addresses.

Here's my code:

```
if( $_POST["submit"] ) {

if (!($stmt =$mysqli->prepare(" SELECT DISTINCT Fname, Minit, Lname, EMPLOYEE.Phone, Address, Sname, Saddress, Dno, Hourly
    FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT, LOCATION
    WHERE EMPLOYEE.Fname=? OR EMPLOYEE.Lname=? OR EMPLOYEE.Dno=? OR LOCATION.Store_num=?"))) {      
print "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ssii",$_POST['Fname'], $_POST['Lname'], $_POST['Dno'], $_POST['Store_num'])) {
print "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    print "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }       
$stmt->store_result();
if (!$stmt->bind_result($Fname,$Minit,$Lname,$Phone,$Address,$Slocation,$Saddress,$Dno,$Hourly)) {
         print "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){
    print "No results were found for the following search <p>"
    .$_POST['Fname'].$_POST['Lname'].$_POST['Store_num'].$_POST['Dno']."</p>";
}

else {
    print "<table border=2 cellpadding=4>

        <tr bgcolor=white>

        <th>First Name</th>

        <th>Middle Initial</th>

        <th>Last Name</th>

        <th>Phone</th>

        <th>Address</th>

        <th>Store</th>

        <th>Store Location</th>

        <th>Dept #</th>

        <th>Hourly Rate</th>

        </tr>";

while ($stmt->fetch()){

    print "<tr><td>".$Fname."</td><td>".$Minit."</td><td>".$Lname.

    "</td><td>".$Phone."</td><td>".$Address."</td><td>".$Slocation."</td>
    <td>".$Saddress."</td><td>".$Dno."</td><td>".$Hourly."</td></tr>";
    }

print "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to dynamically form the SQL query depending on the parameters that are passed in.  It seems that you only want to join the LOCATION table IF the user is trying to filter on that value.  If you join it and they haven't passed a value, it may force extra rows to be returned.

Note also I've assumed that `Dno` is the key joining DEPARTMENT and EMPLOYEE, and that `Store_num` is the the key joining LOCATION and DEPARTMENT - if either are not, just change them to your key. There's a few pieces of information I don't have from your question, but the concept of the following should be what you need to do.

```
$fromClause = '';
$whereClause = '';

// If they have filtered on Store_num, add the relevant bits to the query
$if(isset($_POST['Store_num'])) {
    $fromClause = " INNER JOIN LOCATION ON LOCATION.Store_num = DEPARTMENT.Store_num ";
    $whereClause = " OR LOCATION.Store_num = ?";
}

$query = '
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Fname, Minit, Lname, EMPLOYEE.Phone, Address, Sname, Saddress, Dno, Hourly 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN 
    DEPARTMENT ON DEPARTMENT.Dno = EMPLOYEE.Dno
' . $fromClause . '
WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE.Fname=? OR EMPLOYEE.Lname=? OR EMPLOYEE.Dno=?
' . $whereClause;
```

Comment: Just to provide some additional info, the form uses a multi-field search.